# Insertion finishes before committing in two database tables

Tags: mysql

I have a question related to data synchronization in two database tables. In our system, there is a table named tracking_number_pool and this table exists in two databases, say DB_1 and DB_2. Assume that the system first inserts 100 tracking numbers, which starts from number 1 to number 100, into table tracking_number_pool in DB_1. Then the system decides to delete the first 50 tracking numbers (from 1 to 50) from tracking_number_pool in DB_1 and insert them into table tracking_number_pool in DB_2. One of our rules is that tracking numbers must be unique in both tracking_number_pool tables (namely, a tracking number cannot appear in table tracking_number_pool in DB_1 and DB_2 at the same time). In our implementation, we encouter a problem which is that when deleting a tracking number, say Tracking Number (TN) 49, from DB_1 and inserting it into DB_2, the insert action in DB_2 may finish before the commit for the deletion in DB_1, which causes TR=49 to appear in these two tables simutaneously. I feel that this is a common problem and I would like to know how to solve it.

Comment: No, this is not a common problem. Your implementation is strange. Is there a special reason for this solution?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Now I realize our implemenation is not perfect. It was implemented by my colleagues before. Is there a solution for this problem?

Comment: The logic is as follows: our tracking number generation system generates some tracking numbers when the numbers in tracking_number_pool in DB_1 is less than 10000 numbers, and then inserts the new numbers into DB_1. DB_2 will pull some tracking numbers from DB_1 when the count of tracking numbers in DB_2 is less than some amount  (Say 5000) .

Comment: Hard to say, since we don't know why you  need two databases and tables. Normally you would handle this in a single table.

Comment: I have an idea now. In table tracking_number_pool, we can add a new field named DB_USED, which is used to identify which DB is used for a tracking number. When a tracking number is used in DB_1 the DB_USED field is equal to 'DB_1' and when it is used in DB_2 the field is set to 'DB_2'. This idea may solve the problem.